# Wordpress permalinks with files and folders out site of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I also have pages/files/folders that I've created outsite of wordpress. Right now, I have no permalinks with my URLs as site.com?p=123. I want to have permalinks (pretty links) as site.com/postname (I know the permalink string is /%postname%/). I also have pages that are on my site that have nothing to do with the wordpress site.

When I changed the permalinks in wordpress, all my posts work fine just like they should. But when I try going to an outsite wordpress page/folder like site.com/file_name.php or site.com/folder_name/ I get HTTP 404 not found.

Is there a way that I can do this, or am I stuck with having just the post id permalink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default WordPress `.htaccess` configuration for permalinks should handle files that exist on the file system outside of WordPress. You can read about using permalinks in the [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) documentation on WordPress.

Of note is the snippet that you're supposed to include in `.htaccess` (so maybe update your .htaccess file to contain this content):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The `RewriteCond` clauses tell WordPress that if the current URL either points directly to a file or to a directory, then WordPress will ignore it and let the file load normally.

Comment: I've been doing web programming for a while now, but I've never done anything with .htaccess. Nor have I ever used Wordpress until maybe just a month ago when I totaly changed my site around. Does it make a difference that my Wordpress and all my files are in the docroot? I was reading somewhere that you can install Wordpress to a subfolder and still have the URL point to the root. Is that something that I may have to do?

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether or not WordPress is in docroot or in a subfolder. If WP *is* in a subfolder, though, you'd change `RewriteBase /` line to read `RewriteBase /sub/folder/path`. But you definitely need to have a .htaccess file in the WordPress folder (alongside `wp-config.php`) with the content above if you want to use permalinks as you've described.

Comment: So is there a tutorial or like a ".htaccess for beginners" anywhere? Is there someway that I can make this file for like if the URL is site.com/file_name.php or site.com/folder_name/ then go to it and then after that have what you put above for wordpress?

Comment: Here's a walkthrough that specifically goes through what the WordPress .htaccess file does: [The WordPress .htaccess File Explained](http://randomtype.ca/blog/the-wordpress-htaccess-file-explained/). Also, note that it should fall back to allowing `site.com/file_name.php` and `site.com/folder_name/` if the files / folders do exist (that's what the `RewriteCond` lines say)

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Wordpress .htaccess file after enabling SEO permalinks and add the following line on top:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

Let me know if that works, or you can always explicitly allow those specific files/folders in the .htaccess file.

Comment: I did as you told but my .htaccess file was just empty. So I just put in the line and I got the same thing. Here is a link to my site so you can see what I'm talking about: [link]http://thedynamiclink.com

Comment: You should enable permalinks in the backend first. Your .htaccess file will get populated. Then you can enter that line on the very top.